# Delete regex and non-alphabet characters with grep/awk/sed

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, grep

I'm formatting a linguistic corpus for text input in a phrase generation model. Right now the corpus is essentially a long text file with relevant lines that look like this:

```
*EXP:   I didn't understand what you said .
*CHI:   I know [!] &=laugh (.) .
```

I can already use grep to get all lines that begin with '*'. What I want to do is print out all those lines with the 5-character+tab header removed (delete the *EXP: or *CHI: or whatever) and get rid of all non-alphabet characters like brackets, parens and periods. The only exception is apostrophes - I need to convert apostrophes to the '@' symbol just for this model. Additionally, I want to get rid of tokens that begin with the '&' symbol because they are non-word utterances. So my goal output would be something like this:

```
I didn@t understand what you said

I know
```

I'm very new to Unix text manipulation so I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` to remove the prefix, for example:

```
$ cat corpus.txt | cut -c 9-
I didn't understand what you said .
I know [!] &=laugh (.) .
```

Then to remove the non-word tokens, you can use `sed` like this:

```
$ cat corpus.txt | cut -c 9- | sed 's/\&[^ ]*//g'
I didn't understand what you said .
I know [!]  (.) .
```

And finally, to remove non-alphabetic symbols and convert apostrophes to `@`, you can pipe it into `sed` in two steps like this:

```
$ cat corpus.txt | cut -c 9- | sed 's/\&[^ ]*//g' | sed "s/[^a-zA-Z ']//g" | sed "s/'/@/g"
I didn@t understand what you said
I know
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate the step-by-step walkthrough.

Comment: No problem, that's how I usually think about these problems, break them into steps and then try each one out. That way I know which thing is wrong when something doesn't turn out the way I want.

Comment: try to avoid multi sed separate by pipe if possible (not always), this take lot more ressources, especially interesting on huge file. in this case each `| sed "` could be replaced by a `;` (just use surrounding double quote due to the simple quoute manipulation inside last instruction)

Answer (score 1):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -lne '
    /^\*\w{3}:\s+(.*)/ and do {
        $_ = $1;
        s/[^\w\s\047]//g;
        s/\047/@/g;
        print
    }
' file
```

With explanations :

```
perl -lne ' # using -n is like while (<>) {}
    # regex to match criterias & using capturing group for
    # the interesting ending part :
    /^\*\w{3}:\s+(.*)/ and do {
        $_ = $1; # assigning the captured group on the default variable $_
        s/[^\w\s\047]//g; # replace ponctuation chars by nothing
        s/\047/@/g; # replace single quote with @
        print # print the modified line
    }
' file
```

Output:

```
I didn@t understand what you said 
I know  laugh
```

Comment: Added comments to explain a bit

Comment: Thank you! The more documentation the merrier

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^.....\t//;s/&\S\+//g;y/'\''/\n/;s/[[:punct:]]//g;y/\n/@/' file
```

Remove the front of the line, remove utterances, replace single quotes by newlines, remove punctution and replace newlines by `@`'s.

Comment: `-e "y/'/@"` it is the `'`to change by `@`, `s/^\*....\t//` for line starting with `*` (certainly other inside if the remarq is made) for the rest +1

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk 4.1

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
@include "join"
/^*/ {
  gsub(/'/, "@")
  gsub(/&=\S+/, "")
  gsub(/[^[:alnum:][:blank:]@]/, "")
  split($0, foo)
  print join(foo, 2, NF)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "
# filter line with special starting pattern *AAA:Tab
/^\*[A-Z]\{3}:\t/ {
# remove head using last search pattern by default
   s///
# change quote by @
   y/'/@/
# remove token
   s/\&=[^ ]*//g
# remove non alphabetic (maybe number have to be keep also ?) but @
   s/[^a-zA-Z@]//g
# print only those line
   p
   }" YourFile
```

Posix version (so `--posix` on gnu sed). Could be a OneLine by removing comment and replacing newline by `;` if needed